# What does installing as a service mean?

Tags: tomcat, installation, ubuntu-12.04

When I was installing Tomcat on ubuntu 12.04, I came across the phrase "Install as a service". What does it exactly mean to install something as a service? What other types of install are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomcat could be either started as a normal executable or as a deamon.

Running tomcat as a normal executable is done by calling the bin/startup.sh script (as user or as root using the sudo command).

To start it as a service you have to provide the configuration in the initialization script as explained [in this page](http://www.spaceprogram.com/knowledge/tomcat_init_d.html). Doing that, tomcat can be run during the boot sequence, making it available for all users. It can be controlled using the `service start|stop|status|restart tomcat` command.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please elaborate on what "started as a deamon" mean? Currently I have installed tomcat as a service.  **(1)** Apart from being available to all users, and running during the boot sequence, are there any other advantages of installing as a service?  **(2)** What is the recommended installation for tomcat? i.e. Must it be installed as a service, or as an executable/deamon?  **(3)** What are the pros and cons of both types of installations?  Thank you.

Comment: From wikipedia "In multitasking computer operating systems, a daemon is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user". Deamons are linux services. It means that using a deamon the server will be available as long as the computer is up and running. Using a user process would imply a dependency on a open user session on the server, which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: So, the recommended installation is to install as a service then?

Comment: Unless you are using it for development purpose (only user, frequent restart, ...) using a service is what I would suggest.